# Javascript code can be write it as in a function like?

Tags: javascript

Suppose a function trigger on Click button

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
        <!--getElementsByTagName.html-->
        <head>
            <title>getElementsByTagName.html</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="getElementsByTagName.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                function getData(){
                     inputTag=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                     divOutput=document.getElementById("output");
                     alert(inputTag.length);//length of input Tag
                     for(i=0;i<inputTag.length-1;i++){
                        if((inputTag[i].value=="") || (inputTag[i+1].value=="")){
                            alert("Please Enter Value");
                        }else{
                            a=inputTag[i].value;
                            b=inputTag[i+1].value;
                        }
                     }
                     $("#output").css("display","block");
                     divOutput.innerHTML="<strong>"+a+"<\/strong>";
                     divOutput.innerHTML+="<br\/>"+"<strong>"+b+"<\/strong>";
                }//end function
                //]]>
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Example getElementsByTagName</legend>
                        <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
                        <label for="txtName">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" id="txtPassword"/>
                    <button type="button" onclick="getData()">
                    Submit
                    </button>
                </fieldset> 
                <div id="output">
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Is this right?? $("#output").css("display","block");

This code not working i.e. after click on submit button it doesn't show the output div?

Comment: `$("#output").css("display", "block")`

Comment: Or `$("#output")[0].style.display = "block"`

Comment: ***not working***

Comment: So you're aware, writing `not working` (either using bold/italics or not) tells us nothing. Both solutions above will work... there is obviously something else that isn't working. I would suggest you have an error, which would be visible in your developer tools (F12) console window.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
$( "#output" ).on( "click", function() {
  this.css("display", "block");
});
```